# Modal blocks sorting(?)

Tags: angular, frontend, angular-directive

i'm new to Angular and have some problem.
I have a table in modal and i cant sort it.
I tested the table outside modal and sorting works fine so i assume that problem is with modal.

Can anyone help?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vwy8a2?file=app%2Ftable-sorting-example.html

This my modal function from .ts:

```
 openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(
      template,
      Object.assign({}, { class: 'gray modal-lg' })
    );
  }
```

And html file:

```
<span class="badge badge" (click)="openModal(statusInfoTemp)"><span class="fa fa-comment " ></span> 1</span>           

<ng-template #statusInfoTemp>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-right">Historia zmian</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div>
          <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"  matSort matSortActive="comment" matSortDirection="asc">

              <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
                  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Date </mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let status"> {{status.date | date:'medium'}} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="user">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> User </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let status"> {{status.user}} </mat-cell>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="changedTo">
                      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> changedTo</mat-header-cell>
                      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let status">{{status.changedTo}} </mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>         

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="comment">
                        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Comment </mat-header-cell>
                        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let status"> {{status.comment}} </mat-cell>
                      </ng-container>

                      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" color="primary"></mat-header-row>
                      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
                      </mat-table>

                    </div>

      <div class="modal-footer"> 
      </div>  

</ng-template>
```

Sorry for formatting.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, if you could create a project in stackblitz.com and share the link here we can help you better

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I made smth similar, pls look
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vwy8a2?file=app%2Ftable-sorting-example.html

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the issue is, `ViewChild` is not working in `ng-template`, because it's not part of `DOM`.

For your case you can create a component for your modal and open via component way. [see documentation here](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals)

Then `matSort` will be defined in your dialog component and will work fine

### Steps

1 - Create a new component called StatusInfoDialogComponent and add it as entryComponent in app.module

2 - Move all the html inside ng-template and related code to that component

3 - in your old component.ts change open dialog to something like

```
openModal() {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(
      StatusInfoDialogComponent,
      Object.assign({}, { class: 'gray modal-lg' }) // and pass datasource to that component
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm not sure if i get it fully, could you rewrite my example using component? Anyway, i will dig into. Thanks

Comment: @WiktorWilczak please see steps above